# Center of mass of two sphere system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reference-frames, mass

[image]

I want to know where my approach is wrong in this problem.

Let the mass of bigger sphere be $m_1$ and that of smaller sphere be $m_2$. The bigger sphere has radius $R$ and the smaller one has radius $r$ and $p_1$ is the density of the bigger one and $p_2$ of the smaller one.

Now mass of bigger sphere is $p_1V_1=p_1\times \frac{4}{3}\pi R^3$ and mass of the smaller sphere is $p_2V_2=p_2 \times \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$. So center of mass will be in location $\frac{m_1\times 0+m_2 \times x}{m_1+m_2}$. But i somehow don't get the correct answer.

Comment: Replace $m_2$ by $(\rho_2 - \rho_1) \times V_2$.

Comment: I think you've forgotten that the larger sphere is incomplete. It's missing the part occupied by the smaller sphere. See ytlu's comment.

Comment: ytlu you probabaly mean $m_1$ which is the bigger sphere?Since it's the bigger sphere in which the smaller one resides?

Answer (score 1):

The bigger "sphere" is not actually a sphere. It is a sphere with a spherical hole in it which is occupied by another sphere of a different density. Because of this the mass of the bigger "sphere" is not actually $\rho_1 V_1$. And worse still, its centre of mass is not at its geometrical centre.

The easy way to solve such problems is by addition or subtraction of densities. Instead of all the mass in one region belonging to either  one sphere or to the other, you imagine the impossible : that the two solid spheres "overlap" and share the same space. The overlapping space is occupied both by the bigger sphere of density $\rho_1$ and also the smaller sphere of modified density $\rho_2-\rho_1$. The total density in this region is then $\rho_2$ as required.

Both spheres are now complete and each has uniform density, so you can replace each by a point mass at its geometrical centre.